# Get data between record in table

Tags: sql, oracle, date-range

I have data like this:

[image: Data]

For example, today is on April 2012. Referring to data above, I want to get the data with `M_PER = 03-2012` because this month is in the range `03-2012 TO 06-2012`.

--Edited
In this case, I wanna get a rate for used currency code. Because today is still in April, and I want to know rate US Dollar (USD) to Indonesia Rupiah (IDR) I must get the data with `M_PER = 03-2012` and `CRR_CURRENCY_CODE = USD`.

The question is what query can retrieve data like that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm Using Oracle,.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using quarterly values, I would use the TRUNC function with the `'Q'` format model. This truncates a date to 1/1/YYYY, 1/4/YYYY, 1/7/YYYY and 1/10/YYYY, i.e. the first day of the quarter.

To fit your model which is the month at the end of the quarter, you would then have to add two months. This assumes that the `MONTH_PERIOD` column is a SQL date and not some other data type.

Included below is an example, using SYSDATE as the input date.

```
select *
from your_table
where add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Q'),2) = month_period;
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the rownum and order by to get the value. 
`SELECT * FROM tables WHERE m_per > '04-2012' AND ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY month_period ASC`